# Объясните принцип работы программы, которая удаляет слова из строки

Tags: c, строки

Программа удаляет из строки все одинаковые слова и записывает количество повторов. Каким образом это происходит? Как реализован принцип работы функций?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// ищем самое первое слово в строке
int FindFirstWord(char* text, char** begin, char** end)
{
    for (; *text && !isalpha(*text); ++text) { ; }   // int isalpha(int c) проверяет, является ли передаваемый символ алфавитным

    *begin = text;

    for (; *text && isalpha(*text); ++text) { ; }

    *end = text;

    return (*begin != *end);
}

// двигаем строку
char* PullUpSubstr(char* text, size_t length)
{
    for (; *text; *text = *(text + length), ++text) { ; }

    return text;
}

// сравниваем 2 строки (последовательности)
int CompareSequence(char* first, char* second, size_t length)
{
    for (; *first && *second && length && (*first == *second); ++first, ++second, --length) { ; }

    return (length == 0);
}

// копируем 2 последовательности
char* CopySequence(char* dist, const char* source, size_t length)
{
    for (; *source && length; *dist++ = *source++, --length) { ; }

    return dist;
}

// ищем дубль слово, если нашли, то возвращаем указатель, иначе ноль
char* GetDuplicateWord(char* text, char* word, size_t length)
{
    char* duplicate = NULL;

    char* begin;
    char* end;
    for (; !duplicate && FindFirstWord(text, &begin, &end); text = end + 1)
    {
        if (((end - begin) == length) && CompareSequence(begin, word, length))
        {
            duplicate = begin;
        }
    }

    return duplicate;
}
//----------------------------------------------//
// удаление всех дубль слов
size_t DeleteDuplicate(char* text, char* result)
{
    size_t count = 0;

    char* begin;
    char* end;
    char* cursor;
    int find;

    for (; FindFirstWord(text, &begin, &end); text = end + 1)
    {
        for (cursor = end + 1, find = 0; (cursor = GetDuplicateWord(cursor, begin, end - begin)) != NULL; ++find)
        {
            PullUpSubstr(cursor, end - begin);
        }

        if (find)
        {
            result = CopySequence(result, begin, end - begin);
            *result++ = ' ';
            *result = 0;

            PullUpSubstr(begin, end - begin);
            end = begin;
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}

int main()
{
    printf("Vvedite text (english): ");
    char text[1024];
    fgets(text, sizeof(text) - 1, stdin);

    char result[1024] = { 0 };
    size_t count = DeleteDuplicate(text, result);

    printf("%s%s%u\n", text, result, count);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: очень топорно работает, начиная с того, что требует ввести текст на английском надписью на транслите :) опять же комментарии вам не объясняют принцип? вроде же все написано. в чем именно трудности, в какой функции? - если переписать код на c++ с использованием stl он будет раз в 5 короче

Comment: меня интересует алгоритм самих функций. как именно они выполняют свою работу

Comment: они неэффективно выполняют свою работу - делая много лишнего функционала

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Функция `FindFirstWord`** - функция для поиска первого слова начиная с позиции *text (указатель на строку)

сначала ищется начало слова последовательно перебирая все символы и проверяя, что 1) строка не закончилась, т.е. символ не равен 0, 2) что символ не является буквой

```
*text && !isalpha(*text)
```

результат (позиция/указатель на слово) записывается в переменную `begin`

затем ищется уже конец слова последовательно перебирая все символы и проверяя, что 1) строка не заканчивается, т.е. символ не равен 0, 2) что символ является буквой

*text && isalpha(*text)

результат (позиция/указатель на слово) записывается в переменную `end`

поскольку в С нет ссылок, то для записи значений приходится использовать указатель на переменную, а поскольку в переменной содержится указатель, то получается указатель на указатель - 'char** begin', 'char** end'

в качестве результата функции возвращается значение - содержит ли слово хотя бы 1 букву (не совпадает ли начало и конец найденного слова)

```
*begin != *end
```

это сделано для того, чтобы отследить было ли вообще в строке найдено хоть какое-то слово, например в строке   `12345  @` ни одного слова найдено не будет

Код функции:

```
// ищем самое первое слово в строке
int FindFirstWord(char* text, char** begin, char** end)
{
    for (; *text && !isalpha(*text); ++text) { ; }   // int isalpha(int c) проверяет, является ли передаваемый символ алфавитным

    *begin = text;

    for (; *text && isalpha(*text); ++text) { ; }

    *end = text;

    return (*begin != *end);
}
```

**Функция `PullUpSubstr`** - функция для того, чтобы передвинуть строку на `length` символов влево, например `123xyz` при сдвигании на 3 символа влево превратится в `xyz`

для этого просто происходит перезапись символов в позиции `pos = i` на символы из позиции `pos = i + length`:

```
*text = *(text + length)
```

Код функции:

```
// двигаем строку
char* PullUpSubstr(char* text, size_t length)
{
    for (; *text; *text = *(text + length), ++text) { ; }

    return text;
}
```

**Функция `CompareSequence`** - функция для сравнении двух строк, в которой посимвольно сравниваются строки и определяется все ли символы совпадают

```
// сравниваем 2 строки (последовательности)
int CompareSequence(char* first, char* second, size_t length)
{
    for (; *first && *second && length && (*first == *second); ++first, ++second, --length) { ; }

    return (length == 0);
}
```

для каждого символа проверяется - не является ли он концом строки (не является ли он 0):

```
*first && *second
```

каждый новый символ длина проверяемых символов `length` уменьшается на 1, если проверены все символы (т.е. строки совпадают), то длина будет равна 0, поэтому окончательно для результата сравнивается длина проверяемых символов с 0

```
return (length == 0);
```

**Функция `CopySequence`** - функция для копирования `length` символов из одной строки в начало второй строки

```
// копируем 2 последовательности
char* CopySequence(char* dist, const char* source, size_t length)
{
    for (; *source && length; *dist++ = *source++, --length) { ; }

    return dist;
}
```

копируется максимум `length` символов, проверяя при этом что при копировании символов не достигнут конец строки:

```
*source
```

**Функция `GetDuplicateWord`** - функция, которая ищет первый дубликат слов в строке. После того, как найдено ранее было слово, дальше с позиции где заканчивается слово начинает искаться следующее слово и сравниваться с найденным, если найденное слово совпадает с первым - считается, что дубликат найден и выдается на него указатель

```
// ищем дубль слово, если нашли, то возвращаем указатель, иначе ноль
char* GetDuplicateWord(char* text, char* word, size_t length)
{
    char* duplicate = NULL;

    char* begin;
    char* end;
    for (; !duplicate && FindFirstWord(text, &begin, &end); text = end + 1)
    {
        if (((end - begin) == length) && CompareSequence(begin, word, length))
        {
            duplicate = begin;
        }
    }

    return duplicate;
}
```

**Функция `DeleteDuplicate`** - функция для удаления найденного ранее дубликата для этого в слове для каждого найденного слова ищутся все дубликаты и последовательно сдвигают строку на размер дубликата, чтобы затем заново искать первое слово и проверять его на дубликат

```
// удаление всех дубль слов
size_t DeleteDuplicate(char* text, char* result)
{
    size_t count = 0;

    char* begin;
    char* end;
    char* cursor;
    int find;

    for (; FindFirstWord(text, &begin, &end); text = end + 1)
    {
        for (cursor = end + 1, find = 0; (cursor = GetDuplicateWord(cursor, begin, end - begin)) != NULL; ++find)
        {
            PullUpSubstr(cursor, end - begin);
        }

        if (find)
        {
            result = CopySequence(result, begin, end - begin);
            *result++ = ' ';
            *result = 0;

            PullUpSubstr(begin, end - begin);
            end = begin;
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

В общем алгоритм простой:

1. в строке ищем первое слово
2. если слово не найдено - заканчиваем выполнение программы и выводим счетчик дубликатов
3. если слово найдено, то с позиции после конца слова ищем последовательно слова
4. найденное слово проверяется с первоначальным
5. если слова совпадают, то счетчик дубликатов увеличивается на 1, а строка смещается на начало позиции дубликата
6. опять выполняется п. 3)
7. опять выполняется п. 1)
8. возвращается счетчик дубликатов

**P.S.**

даже для C алгоритм очень топорный (много лишнего функционала, не используются доступные функции, например для сравнения строк), можно сделать проще, красивее и гораздо быстрее!!!

если же использовать C++ и STL, то можно сделать еще более короткий и понятный код